# called web service do not display in fiddler

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, fiddler

i have added in project reference to web service from wdsl file and call her like function

```
...
MyService service = new MyService();
service.webMethod(arg0, arg1);
...
```

after this I do not have her in showed in fiddler. How can I fix it? Thx

Comment: There's not nearly enough information here to help.  How have you set up fiddler?  Note that I think there are some challenges testing a local WCF service in Fiddler (there's probably a number of articles on this on the web).

Comment: no, I does not set him ... i've try to check some article for that